# jquery validation rules not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I created an update form wherein you can update each field individually. One of my fields is for password reset. I've been trying to use the jquery function validate to make validations for this field. I've tested in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUYvS/147/) and the code works perfectly. Strangely however, when I run my actual php script, the validation messages don't appear to work. My the code in jsfiddle, is pretty much the same as the one in my php script (Except for the value of the password field. Here's the snippet from my script:

```
<form method="POST" id="update_password">
<div>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user_password" value="if(isset($_POST['user_password'])){ echo $_POST['user_password']; } else { echo $session_username; }" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_password"/>
</div>
</form>
```

So my question is pretty much simple, how come this code snippet works on jsfiddle but not on my actual php script when I run it in localhost? Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: You should never be storing passwords in plaintext yet alone loading them into the page markup over HTTP. This is very insecure, not to mention pointless as the user would only ever see asterisks in the field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the PHP opening and closing tags.

```
<form method="POST" id="update_password">
<div>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="user_password" name="user_password" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['user_password'])){ echo $_POST['user_password']; } else { echo $session_username; }?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_password"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Also I'm not sure why you would want to print the "session_username" in the password field...